# Error in AWS SageMaker Ground Truth labeled job creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ground-truth

I'm using AWS SageMaker Ground Truth for labeling images. I have uploaded the data into s3 bucket, create the IAM role to access 'S3,SageMaker,Groundtruth, and IAM'. When I am trying to create labeling job, it give me this error:

> NetworkingError: Network Failure - The S3 bucket 'sm-gt-s3-enron' you entered in Input dataset location cannot be reached. Either the bucket does not exist, or you do not have permission to access it. If the bucket does not exist, update Input dataset location with a new S3 URI. If the bucket exists, give the IAM entity you are using to create this labeling job permission to read and write to this S3 bucket, and try your request again.

Answer (score 1):

From the error, it looks like either you:

1. have not created the bucket in the same region where you are running the labeling job.
   OR
2. have not provided correct IAM permissions for the execution role attached to this labeling job.

The role info you share in the question, is it your logged in IAM role info or the execution role info attached to the labeling job?

Can you try accessing the S3 bucket from your local CLI, or from an EC2 instance in the same region?